# Does redux-form change prop argument value as function work?

Tags: redux-form

I have `"redux-form": "^7.4.2"`.
I see in the docs:

> change(field:String, value:any) : Function Changes the value of a
>   field in the Redux store. This is a bound action creator, so it
>   returns nothing. You could get current field-value & form-values while
>   value is a function, For example: change(field, (fieldValue,
>   allValues) => {})

I try to do:

```
dispatch(
      change(formName, fieldName, (val, allValues) => {
        /* do something with arguments */
        return theResultOfTheAboveCode;
      }),
    );
```

It does not work. But the below code works fine:

```
dispatch(change(formName, fieldName, someValue));
```

Does the function as the value work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `7.4.2` which does not have the value as function.

The docs are under https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/props.md/

The value as a function exists on the newest 8.x.x https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/props.md/